# dompdf special character showing question mark?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, dompdf

I have used dompdf 0.5.1 for generating PDF files. But the special characters are not properly showing.

For example, [image].

It is showing something like `â€“ â€œ` in the generated PDF file.

I used UTF-8 encoding like
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the HTML page which is rendered by the dompdf.

I also have used the encoding before sending it to dompdf, like
`$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($html));`.

But I get `?` marks instead of the above characters.

How do I solve the above problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dompdf 0.5.1 has limited support for characters that aren't supported by Windows ANSI encoding. If you need to support these characters you should update to, at the very least, [Dompdf 0.6.2](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.6.2). Though I'd recommend using [Dompdf 0.7.0](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v0.7.0) if you can.

You'll need to supply a font that supports your characters (see the [Unicode How-To](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/UnicodeHowTo)), but so long as you're not trying to render CJK characters you can probably rely on the included DejaVu fonts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style>
    * { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>—</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you should *never* use `utf8_decode()` as it will destructively convert to iso-8859-1 encoding. By destructively I mean that it will change characters it can't directly convert to iso-8859-1 in question marks (?).

Comment: I updated it to Dompdf 0.6.2.. it is working fine. Thanks @BrianS.

Comment: I have Dompdf 0.8.2 installed and at first it outputted `ŉ`, which is equivalent to `a` in English, into `?`.  I forgot of course that laravel `{{ }}` escapes characters, so I changed it to `{!! !!}` which solved it for some of the `ŉ` characters.  I had copied the text from a pdf I had received to insert on a site,  which had an encoding for the `ŉ` character that could not be converted.  Solution of course was to turn the `ŉ` character into two characters namely an apostrophe + the letter `n` i.e. `'n`.