# Print INR symbol in PDF using DomPDF

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, dompdf

I want to print INR (Indian rupee) symbol in PDF but failed, when PDF got generated it shows `?` instead on `₹`.

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.3"
```

I have generated PDF like :

```
   use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

   $pdf = PDF::loadView('report-test')->setPaper('a4');
   return $pdf->stream('payslip.pdf');
```

PDF Html :

```
<p>Price &#x20b9; 9500 = &#x20b9; 9500</p>
 <p>Price &#8377; 5500 = &#8377; 5500</p>
 <p>Price &#8360; 500 = &#8360; 500</p>
 <p>Price &#x20a8; 2000 = &#x20a8; 2000</p>
 <p>Price &#8377; 2000 = &#x20B9; 2000</p>
 <p style="font-family: dejavusans !important;">Price &#2352; rupee </p>
 <p>I will display &#8377;</p>
 <p>I will display &#x20B9;</p>
```

Also i have added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` in header, still no luck.

Anything i am missing?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dompdf special character showing question mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718881/dompdf-special-character-showing-question-mark)

Comment: Just make sure you specify a font that supports your glyphs. The bundled DejaVu fonts will work.