# phpword dompdf docx to pdf special character

Tags: php, dompdf

```
<?php 
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$domPdfPath = realpath('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

// //Load temp file
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('test.docx'); 


// //Save it
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord , 'PDF');
//  
$xmlWriter->setFont('arial');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
$xmlWriter->save('php://output'); 
?>
```

word to pdf works fine but
Turkish characters in the resulting pdf '?' looks like

Comment: May be this link helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718881/dompdf-special-character-showing-question-mark

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dompdf special character showing question mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718881/dompdf-special-character-showing-question-mark)