# Laravel dompdf character encoding UTF-8

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF with correct characters using Laravel and dompdf but there is a "?" characters. I have created a test php file where I am trying to find the best solution. If I open an HTML browser I look fine

Take an example from this github

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Checkout</title>

<style>
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }

      body {
        color: #333333;
        font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
        background-color: rgb(230, 227, 227);
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
      }

      .container {
        padding: 80px 100px 42px 45px;
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 1px #333;
      }

      header {
        display: flex;
        gap: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }

      nav {
        width: 70%;
      }

      .nav-top {
        display: flex;
        gap: 12px;
      }

      .nav-top img {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
      }

      h1 {
        font-size: 42px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
      }

      .nav-top P {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      aside {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 25px;
      }

      .aside-label {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
      }

      .aside-value {
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      .aside-value span {
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      .nav-bottom {
        margin-top: 30px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(209, 202, 202);
      }

      .nav-bottom h2 {
        margin-bottom: 12px;
      }

      .passengers {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .passengers .first-cell {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(209, 202, 202);
      }

      .passengers .first-col {
        width: 60%;
      }

      .passengers .second-col,
      .passengers .third-col {
        width: 20%;
      }

      .cell {
        display: flex;
      }

      .first-cell {
        font-size: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 2px;
      }

      .second-cell {
        padding-top: 8px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      .direction {
        padding-bottom: 50px;
      }

      .direction-title {
        display: flex;
        align-items: end;
        gap: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
      }

      .direction-title p {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .direction tr:first-child {
        font-size: 12px;
      }

      .direction tr:first-child td {
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(209, 202, 202);
      }

      .direction tr:last-child td,
      .direction tr:nth-child(2) td {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-right: 32px;
      }

      table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        max-width: 95%;
      }

      table td {
        vertical-align: top;
      }

      .direction tr:last-child td {
        border-top: 1px solid rgb(209, 202, 202);
      }

      .direction tr:first-child td.last-item {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
      }

      .direction-text {
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .direction-item__title {
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      .direction td:first-child {
        width: 140px;
      }

      .last-item {
        padding-left: 24px;
        border-top: 1px solid #ffffff !important;
      }

      .information {
        display: flex;
        gap: 80px;
      }

      .information-block {
        padding-top: 16px;
        border-top: 4px solid gray;
        width: 50%;
      }

      .information-block h2 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .info-text {
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .info-text.first {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
      }

      .hints {
        display: flex;
        gap: 16px;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .hints div {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-start;
        gap: 30px;
      }

      .hints div img {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
      }

      .prices-block {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
      }

      .prices-block li {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 4px;
      }

      .price__label {
        width: 50%;
      }

      .price__value {
        font-weight: 600;
      }

      .prices-extra {
        padding-left: 8px;
      }

      .amount {
        padding-top: 16px;
        padding-bottom: 50px;
        border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
      }

      .amount-top {
        display: flex;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .amount-top h2 {
        font-size: 28px;
        width: 50%;
      }

      .amount-value {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 30px;
      }

      .nds {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .comment {
        width: 50%;
      }

      .amount-bottom {
        display: flex;
      }

      .extra {
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      .amount-block {
        width: 50%;
      }

      .address {
        padding-top: 16px;
      }

      .address p {
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      footer {
        margin-top: 20vh;
      }

      .footer-text {
        max-width: 60%;
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <nav>
          <div class="nav-top">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
            <div>
              <h1>Маршрутная квитанция электронного билета</h1>
              <p>Внимание! Это не посадочный талон</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="nav-bottom">
            <h2>Пассажиры</h2>
            <div class="passengers">
              <div class="first-cell cell">
                <div class="first-col"></div>
                <div class="second-col">Документ</div>
                <div class="third-col">Номер билета</div>
              </div>
              <div class="second-cell cell">
                <div class="first-col">MRS TEST TESTOV</div>
                <div class="second-col">402111111</div>
                <div class="third-col">42111111111</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <aside>
          <div class="aside-item">
            <p class="aside-label">Бронирование</p>
            <p class="aside-value"><span>S7 - </span>LOUJ9V</p>
          </div>
          <div class="aside-item">
            <p class="aside-label">Оформлено</p>
            <p class="aside-value">25 мая 2023</p>
          </div>
          <div class="aside-item">
            <p class="aside-label">Статус</p>
            <p class="aside-value">Подтверждено</p>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </header>
      <section class="direction">
        <div class="direction-title">
          <h2>Маршрут</h2>
          <p>Указано местное время</p>
        </div>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>Рейс</td>
            <td>Отправление</td>
            <td>Прибытие</td>
            <td>Класс и Тариф</td>
            <td>Багаж</td>
            <td class="last-item">Регистрация до</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="direction-item">
                <p class="direction-item__title">S7 5552</p>
                <p class="direction-text">S7 Airlines Airbus A320</p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="direction-item">
                <p class="direction-item__title">04 июн.</p>
                <p class="direction-text">00:20 Душанбе, Душанбе</p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="direction-item">
                <p class="direction-item__title">04 июн.</p>
                <p class="direction-text">
                  05:35 Новосибирск, Толмачево Терминал B
                </p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="direction-text">RSTOVB Эконом Стандарт</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="direction-text">
                1 место до 23 кг Ручная кладь до 10 кг
              </p>
            </td>
            <td class="last-item">
              <p class="direction-item__title">23:40</p>
              <p class="direction-text">00:20 Душанбе, Душанбе</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="direction-item">
                <p class="direction-item__title">S7 5239</p>
                <p class="direction-text">S7 Airlines Airbus A320</p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="direction-item">
                <p class="direction-item__title">04 июн.</p>
                <p class="direction-text">
                  21:10 Новосибирск, Толмачево Терминал A
                </p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="direction-item">
                <p class="direction-item__title">05 июн.</p>
                <p class="direction-text">05:00 Хабаровск, Хабаровск (Новый)</p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="direction-text">RSTOVB Эконом Стандарт</p>
            </td>
            <td>
              <p class="direction-text">
                1 место до 23 кг Ручная кладь до 10 кг
              </p>
            </td>
            <td class="last-item">
              <p class="direction-item__title">20:30</p>
              <p class="direction-text">21:10 Новосибирск, Толмачево</p>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </section>
      <section class="information">
        <div class="information-block">
          <h2>Информация</h2>
          <p class="info-text first">
            Быстрый доступ к информации о вашем бронировании: проверьте детали
            вашего маршрута, отправьте билет родным и близким или внесите
            изменения в данные пассажиров.
          </p>
          <div class="hints">
            <div>
              <img src="images/icons/1.png" alt="Hour" />
              <p class="info-text">
                Рекомендуем приехать в аэропорт минимум за 2 часа до вылета.
                Комфортный запас времени избавит вас от лишних хлопот и суеты
                перед рейсом. Регистрация на рейс открывается за 30 часов и
                закрывается за 40 минут до вылета самолета. Вы можете
                зарегистрироваться самостоятельно на сайте s7.ru, c помощью
                приложения S7 для iPhone и Android или через киоски
                самостоятельной регистрации.
              </p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="images/icons/2.png" alt="Case" />
              <p class="info-text">
                Если вес, количество или габариты вашего багажа превышают
                бесплатную норму, свяжитесь с нашим Контактным центром для его
                оформления.<br /><br />
                Статусный участник S7 Priority может провозить дополнительный
                багаж БЕСПЛАТНО!
              </p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <img src="images/icons/3.png" alt="Phone" />
              <p class="info-text">
                Остались вопросы? Свяжитесь с нашим круглосуточным Контактным
                Центром по телефону 8-800-700-0707 (бесплатно для звонков из
                России) или +7(495)777-9999
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="information-block">
          <div class="prices">
            <h2>Стоимость</h2>
            <ul class="prices-block">
              <li>
                <p class="price__label">Тариф</p>
                <p class="price__value">346 EUR</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p class="price__label">Эквивалент</p>
                <p class="price__value">30 105 RUB</p>
              </li>
              <li>
                <p class="price__label">Таксы</p>
                <p class="price__value">845 RUB</p>
              </li>
              <li class="prices-extra">RUB 382RI</li>
              <li class="prices-extra">RUB 296RI</li>
              <li class="prices-extra">RUB 167RI</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="amount">
            <div class="amount-top">
              <h2>Итого</h2>
              <div class="amount-block">
                <p class="amount-value">30 950 RUB</p>
                <p class="nds">Включая НДС 0 RUB</p>
                <p class="extra">
                  INVOICE IN/A/ESINP <br />
                  30 950 RUB
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="amount-bottom">
              <p class="comment">Примечания</p>
              <div class="amount-block">
                <p class="extra">
                  S7 <br />
                  ONLY/REF/CHNG/RESTR/ST/INCL <br />
                  VAT0.00RUB RATE <br />
                  1EUR=87.000000RUB
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="address">
            <h2>Офис оформления</h2>
            <p>
              S7 Airlines, Ариана, Худжанд. Таджикистан, г.Худжанд, ул.К.Маркс
              22
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <footer>
        <p class="footer-text">
          Внимание: перевозка и другие предоставляемые перевозчиком услуги
          подчиняются всем условиям договора перевозки с S7 Airlines или иного
          перевозчика, фактически выполняющего ваш рейс, а также правилам
          применения выбранного вами тарифа. Условия вашего договора перевозки,
          а также вышеуказанные условия применения тарифа и правила перевозки
          включены в настоящий авиабилет посредством ссылки на таковые. С
          условиями договора перевозки (правилами перевозки, правилами
          применения тарифов) можно ознакомиться в офисах продаж, на сайте S7
          Airlines или перевозчика, фактически выполняющего ваш рейс. К
          перевозке, имеющей пункт назначения или остановку не в стране
          отправления, могут применяться положения варшавской или монреальской
          конвенции, которые определяют и могут ограничивать ответственность
          перевозчика за смерть или причинение вреда здоровью пассажира, а также
          за утрату или повреждение багажа.
        </p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

But when i try to upload to pdf some characters become ?????

What Im doing wrong? I tried many many options which I found :( Any idea?

Comment: I would strongly suggest to remove any sensitive data from the code sample.

Comment: @BlitZ, i did .

Comment: did you try this? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38730069/11377411

Comment: @KavanPrajapati, yes i have already declared font-family: DejaVu Sans

Comment: version of dompdf need to be 0.6 or more in order to support this, check which version you're using from composer.json file

Comment: @KavanPrajapati, my version "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^2.0",